# Saving real time data in Python

Tags: excel, wxpython, python-3.8, saving-data, real-time-data

I have a python interface of a software which stores data from the camera in excel. The software working is when I click Ready the camera starts recording and status shows(Running) and then when i click on the same tab it stops. NOw i want to write the current data in excel. Currently it is saving all the previous values.

It would be very helpful if i could get help on this as I am new to Python.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.activex
import csv
import comtypes.client


class EventSink(object):

    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.counter = 0
        self.frame = frame

    def DataReady(self):
        self.counter +=1
        self.frame.Title= "DataReady fired {0} times".format(self.counter)

class MyApp( wx.App ): 

    def OnClick(self,e):
        
        rb_selection = self.rb.GetStringSelection()
        if rb_selection == "WinCam":
            data = self.gd.ctrl.GetWinCamDataAsVariant()
            data = [[x] for x in data]
        else:
            p_selection = self.cb.GetStringSelection()
            if p_selection == "Profile_X":
                data = self.px.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [[x] for x in data]#csv.writerows accepts a list of rows where each row is a list, a list of lists
            elif p_selection == "Profile_Y":
                data = self.py.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [[x] for x in data]
            **elif p_selection =="data_info":
                while self.data18 ==1:  
                    data= [self.data1,self.data2,self.data3,self.data4,self.data5,self.data6,self.data7,self.data8,self.data9,self.data10,self.data11,self.data12,self.data13,self.data14,self.data15,self.data16,self.data17,self.data18]
                    b=data
                    file = open('C:\\Users\\Namrata\\data.csv', 'w') 
                    with file:  
                        a = ['Clip Level a', 'Clip level b', 'Major','Minor','Mean','Eff_2W','Ellip','Orient','Crosshair','Xc','Yc','Centroid','Rc','ADC Peak','Exposure','image zoom','plateau uniformity'] 
                        zip(a,b)
                        out = csv.writer(file)
                        out.writerows(zip(a,b))
                        file.close()**
            
            else:
                datax = self.px.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                datay = self.py.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [list(row) for row in zip(datax,datay)]#Makes a list of lists; X1 with Y1 in a list, X2 with Y2 in a list etc...
                filename = self.ti.Value
                with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
                    w = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                    w.writerows(data)

   

    def __init__( self, redirect=False, filename=None ):
        wx.App.__init__( self, redirect, filename )
        self.frame = wx.Frame( parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY,size=(1000,760), title='Python Interface to DataRay')
        #Panel
        p = wx.Panel(self.frame, wx.ID_ANY)
        #Get Data
        self.gd = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(p, 'DATARAYOCX.GetDataCtrl.1')
        #The methods of the object are available through the ctrl property of the item
        self.gd.ctrl.StartDriver()
        self.counter = 0
        sink = EventSink(self.frame)
        self.sink = comtypes.client.GetEvents(self.gd.ctrl, sink)
    
        
    
        #Button Panel
        bp = wx.Panel(parent=self.frame, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=(300, 400))
        b1 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(280,25), pos=(20, 0),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b1.ctrl.ButtonID =297
        self.data18= b1.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b1.ctrl.GetParameter()#Id's for some ActiveX controls must be set
        b2 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5, 30),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b2.ctrl.ButtonID =294
        self.data1= b2.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b3 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150,30),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b3.ctrl.ButtonID =295
        data2= b3.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b4 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5,60),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b4.ctrl.ButtonID =180
        data3= b4.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b5 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 60),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b5.ctrl.ButtonID =181
        self.data4= b5.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b6 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5, 90),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b6.ctrl.ButtonID =182
        data5= b6.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b7 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 90),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b7.ctrl.ButtonID =95
        data6= b7.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b8 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5, 120),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b8.ctrl.ButtonID =177
        data7= b8.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b9 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 120),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b9.ctrl.ButtonID =179
        data8= b9.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b10 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5,150),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b10.ctrl.ButtonID =302
        data9= b10.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b11= wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 150),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b11.ctrl.ButtonID =171
        data10= b11.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b12 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5, 180),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b12.ctrl.ButtonID =172
        data11= b12.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b13 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 180),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b13.ctrl.ButtonID =298
        data12= b13.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b14 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5, 210),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b14.ctrl.ButtonID =425
        data13= b14.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b15 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 210),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b15.ctrl.ButtonID =183
        data14= b15.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b16 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(5, 240),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b16.ctrl.ButtonID =409
        data15= b16.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b17 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(140,25), pos=(150, 240),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b17.ctrl.ButtonID =301
        data16= b17.ctrl.GetParameter()
        b18 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(280,25), pos=(5, 270),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b18.ctrl.ButtonID =291
        data17= b18.ctrl.GetParameter()
        
        #Custom controls
        t = wx.StaticText(bp, label="File:", pos=(5, 300))
        self.ti = wx.TextCtrl(bp, value="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\output.csv", pos=(30, 300), size=(170, -1))
        self.rb = wx.RadioBox(bp, label="Data:", pos=(5, 330), choices=["Profile", "WinCam","Data Info"])
        self.cb = wx.ComboBox(bp, pos=(5,380), choices=[ "Profile_X", "Profile_Y", "data_info","Both"])
        self.cb.SetSelection(0)
        myb = wx.Button(bp, label="Write", pos=(150,380))
        myb.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        myd = wx.Button(bp, label="Dialog", pos=(150,330))
        myd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        
        #Pictures
        pic = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,400),axID='DATARAYOCX.CCDimageCtrl.1')
        tpic = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,400), axID='DATARAYOCX.ThreeDviewCtrl.1')
        palette = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(10,250), axID='DATARAYOCX.PaletteBarCtrl.1')
        #Profiles
        self.px = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,300),axID='DATARAYOCX.ProfilesCtrl.1')
        self.px.ctrl.ProfileID=22
        self.py = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,300),axID='DATARAYOCX.ProfilesCtrl.1')
        self.py.ctrl.ProfileID = 23
        self.ax = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(150,360),axID='DATARAYOCX.getdataCtrl.1')
        #Formatting 
        row1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row1.Add(window=bp,flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        row1.Add(pic)
        row1.Add(window=tpic, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        row2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row2.Add(self.px, 0, wx.RIGHT, 100)# Arguments: item, proportion, flags, border
        row2.Add(self.py)
        col1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        col1.Add(sizer=row1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        col1.Add(sizer=row2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.frame.SetSizer(col1)
        self.frame.Show()
       

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = MyApp()
     app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

to save data in real time you can do this:

first create a `wx.timer` that fires constantly:

```
self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
self.timer.start(#here you have to specify the amount of milliseconds the timer sleep before fire again)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
```

then you create the `OnTimer()` function to store data in the excel file:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def OnTimer(self, event):

    data = #here you get your data

    wb = load_workbook('path/to/yout/excel/file.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active()


    #here you have to play with cells rows and cols by inserting data and saving, 
    #for more info go to the below link
```

[openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html)